# How do I show a datetime column from datatable with the "dd/mm/yyyy" format in a datagrid?

Tags: vb.net

i have a datatable which i am binding to a datagrid. On of the column in datatable has data of datetime format. i want to convert all the values under that column to "dd/mm/yyyy" format . I want to make the required changes from code behind.

```
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            gdvImport.DataSource = dt
            gdvImport.DataBind()
        End If
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246840/how-do-i-display-mm-dd-yyyy-no-time-in-my-datagridview-column

Comment: that didnt help .. i am using vb.net.  i tried using dataGridView1.Columns["dateReceived"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy"; but it showed error "DefaultCellStyle is not a member of System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField"